# Only show my float number to a certain decimal place - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

basically I want to remove the decimal places for my step calories burnt calculation. I know I need to add something to `self.total2.text = ("\(String(bmi)) kcal")` but just need a quick bit of advice on achieving this.

```
 @IBAction func calc2(_ sender: Any) {
        if self.value111.text! != "" && self.value222.text! != "" {
            let textfieldInt = Float(value111.text!)
            let textfield2Int = Float(value222.text!)
            var bmi:Float = (((textfieldInt! * 2.204623) * 0.5) / 1500) * textfield2Int!
            self.total2.text = ("\(String(bmi)) kcal")
            let banner = StatusBarNotificationBanner(title: "Calculation Done! Submit to save. ✅", style: .warning)
            banner.show(queuePosition: .front)
        }
    }
    @IBAction func submit2(_ sender: Any) {
        let dict = (["kcal": self.total.text!, "date": self.getDate()])
        ref?.child("user").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("measurements").child("calculations").child("kcal").child("\(getDate())").setValue(dict)
        total.text = ""
        let banner = NotificationBanner(title: "Success, Step Calories Burnt has been saved today ⚖️", style: .success)
        banner.show(queuePosition: .front)
    }
```

Comment: *remove the decimal places* and *show ... to a certain decimal place* are two different things and there are different solutions for each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `NumberFormatter` (have a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter))

```
let bmi:Float = (((textfieldInt! * 2.204623) * 0.5) / 1500) * textfield2Int!

let formatter = NumberFormatter()

//Set the min and max number of digits to your liking, make them equal if you want an exact number of digits
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3

self.total2.text = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: bmi)) + " kcal"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `NumberFormatter` class, which lets you fine-tune the string representation of a numeric value, whether integer or floating-point. Set up the `NumberFormatter` to produce the output in the format you want, then call `string(from:)` to create a string from your number.